# ReferenceError: can't find variable: document

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, native

i'm creating a simple mobile app using react native. the project worked fine on simulators until I added redux. I'm using redux for logging on and off; its really only a reducer and action files to set authedUser with registered username when logging in, and to null when logging out. if I run it on a web browser it works fine, but doesn't work on ios/android simulators. When running on simulators through `react-native run-android` I get the above error. and when running it via expo I get: Invariant Violation: “main” has not been registered.
[here is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MasqN.png)
totally lost. Any suggestions?

package.json content:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.10",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.62.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.0.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document please look at this link it covers what is a `document`. basically document object only available inside web browser. So in your redux code, you may be trying to use it. so it will not work on mobile devices because it does not have `document`.

Comment: and please make sure to include code while asking questions, it will help us understand your problem more easily.

Comment: Isn't `React-dom` specific to browsers?

Comment: How was this resolved? Were you able to run something that uses document or window on the device with react native?

Answer (score 1):

When you run your app in simulator with debugging mode, since the debugger is chrome devtools, it will know the instance of document and it is not creating any error. Basically you are using some npm module that is used by webapp in your react native app. Can you list the contents of your package.json file.

Comment: I added package.json to the post